# Changes not reflected in List Tile despite data passed correctly from another screen

Tags: flutter, dart

**latest edit:**problem solved, i added as many debugging statements and turned out i wasnt passing existing task's id to edited element.
So here's a lesson for beginners like me:
***Whenever you get stuck, add debugging statements to test where the problem is occuring and then figure out how to fix it.***

[**found the error** so apparently the element's id and editedElement's id are not matching, gotta do a deep check sighs]

I have a task tile in tasksList, i am updating this task tile, i added debugging statmenets and it turned out everything is working fine, data is being updated but in list, its not updated as following piece of code isnt working, as the debugging statement didnt get orint here:

```
if(editedTodo != null){
      print("After navigation - Edited Task Title: ${editedTodo.title}, Edited Task Description: ${editedTodo.description}");
      int editedTaskIndex = tasksList.indexWhere((element) => element.id == editedTodo.id);

//from here its not working as this statement below isnt getting printed
      if(editedTaskIndex != -1){
        setState(() {
          tasksList[editedTaskIndex] = editedTodo;
          print("After updating tasksList - Task Title: ${tasksList[editedTaskIndex].title}, Task Description: ${tasksList[editedTaskIndex].description}");
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

What might be the problem?

I dont know why its not updating the task details in list. If anyone can explain and show the correct way to do so, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

None of your code seems off at a glance,
However, one probable issue could be with the list `tasksList` inside your `_TasklistScreenState`.

The reason your Edited Task may not be getting updated could be due to the use of `final` keyword for `tasksList`. In Dart, final means single-assignment. A final variable or field must have an initializer. Once assigned a value, a final variable's value cannot be changed.

Try changing `final tasksList = Todo.todoList();` to `List<Todo> tasksList = Todo.todoList();`.

And in your `_onLongPressed` function, ensure that the editedTodo.id is correctly matching with an id of a Todo object within your tasksList. It seems like the `editedTaskIndex` might be -1, which could indicate no match was found for the id within your tasksList.

Also, in your `build` method, you seem to be iterating over `_foundToDo.reversed`. Ensure that this list is updated whenever `tasksList` is updated, if they are meant to be in sync.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Daniel. I added debugging statment for editedTtaskIndex and got to know error is there. so gotta fix it myself.

Comment: Can i connect with you on linked?